# Silverlight (WP7) variable sized array?

Tags: c#, arrays, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want an array of strings whose size is variable and changes while the app is running, like Cocoa's NSMutableArray.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("a");
strings.Add("b");

int size = strings.Count;
```